# How to cancel futures binance order?

Tags: python, binance

I'm working with **python-binance**. In my code, I place a futures **market** order, using this code:

```py
order = self.client.futures_create_order(
                symbol=coin_pare,
                type='MARKET',
                side=route,
                quantity=value * self.main_leverage,

            )
```

Then, when I want to close this order, I decide to use cancel_order in this library, using this code:

```py
self.client.cancel_order(symbol=pare, orderId=order_id, origClientOrderId=client_order_id)
```

And I get an error: `APIError(code=-2011): Unknown order sent.`
Is there another way how to cancel certain order?

Answer (score 0):

timestamp is mandatory in parameters for cancel orders mentioned in https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#query-order-user_data
you should edit like this:

```
(self.client.cancel_order(symbol=pare, orderId=order_id, origClientOrderId=client_order_id, timestamp=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove spaces and encode the string.
Do this:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
from json import dumps
    
    order_id_str = dumps(order_id).replace(" ", "")
    order_id_str = quote(order_id_str)
    self.client.cancel_order(symbol=pare, orderIdList=order_id_str)
```